# Show -1 if scale is more than 2

Tags: sql-server

I have table which has two `sql_variant` columns . In the first column, a decimal value is inserted as a varchar. In the second column a decimal value is inserted as decimal itself.

```
DECLARE  @ATempSelected TABLE(RowNum [int] ,Quantity1 sql_variant,
Quantity2 sql_variant)

INSERT INTO @ATempSelected
SELECT 1,  '18.33',18.33
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  '18.555555',18.555555
```

I should convert the sql_variant as decimal ResultantValue only if the scale is less than or equal to 2. Otherwise I need to show -1 in the ResultantValue. I have following case statement.

```
SELECT T.Quantity1, 
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(T.Quantity1,'Scale')  ScaleValue1, 
        CASE WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(T.Quantity1,'Scale') <= 2 THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),T.Quantity1) ELSE -1 END  AS ResultantValue1,
        T.Quantity2, 
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(T.Quantity2,'Scale')  ScaleValue2, 
        CASE WHEN SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(T.Quantity2,'Scale') <= 2 THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),T.Quantity2) ELSE -1 END  AS ResultantValue2
FROM @ATempSelected T
```

The [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx) is giving `scale` zero for value '18.555555'.

What is the best approach for the above logic (show -1, if the scale is more than 2) in `SQL Server 2012`?

Note: The actual value entered will be either integer or decimal (but received as a varchar). This validation is already in place in steps before this code, iin the client application. I only need to validate the `scale`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is what I am using now, till I get a better answer.

```
DECLARE  @ATempSelected TABLE(RowNum [int] ,Quantity1 VARCHAR(100), NewQuantity VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @ATempSelected(RowNum,Quantity1)
SELECT 1,  '18.33'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  '18.555555'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,  '18'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  '17.'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  '16.1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,  '1234567.1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,  '1234567'
UNION ALL
SELECT 8,  'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 8,  '1e4'


UPDATE @ATempSelected SET NewQuantity = Quantity1
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Quantity1 + 'e0')  = 1

UPDATE @ATempSelected SET NewQuantity = '-1'
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Quantity1 + 'e0')  = 0


SELECT T.Quantity1,T.NewQuantity,
       --,ScaleLength.*,
       LEN(T.NewQuantity) AS LengthOfString,
       CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity) as IndexVal,
       CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity) > 0 THEN LEN(T.NewQuantity)-CHARINDEX('.',T.Quantity1) ELSE 0 END AS Scale,
       CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity) > 0 THEN (LEN(T.NewQuantity) - (LEN(T.NewQuantity)-CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity))-1) ELSE LEN(T.NewQuantity) END AS NumericPart
       ,CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity) = 0 AND LEN(T.NewQuantity) <= 6 THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),T.NewQuantity) --No decimal places
            WHEN CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity) = 0 AND LEN(T.NewQuantity) > 6 THEN -1   --No decimal places; but exceeds the numbers in numeric part
            WHEN LEN(T.NewQuantity)-CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity) <= 2  
                AND (LEN(T.NewQuantity) - (LEN(T.NewQuantity)-CHARINDEX('.',T.NewQuantity))-1) <= 6 
                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),T.NewQuantity)  --Decimal places present + Scale is 2 or less + Numeric Part is 6 or less
            ELSE -1
       END AS Result
FROM @ATempSelected AS T
```

Answer (score 1):

Quantity1 is varchar so the default scale would be 0 >>> "all other types" <<<

```
Scale   decimal (p,s) and numeric (p,s) = s
        money and smallmoney = 4
        datetime = 3
        all other types = 0
```

To toggle, perhaps

```
IIF(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(T.Quantity2,'Scale')>2,-1,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(T.Quantity2,'Scale')),
```

> **EDIT**

Just because you got me curious, I created a UDF to return the scale.  This way you can return the record level scale.

**EDIT 2: Added an option to strip trailing zeros**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Stat-Scale](@Value varchar(50),@Strip0s Bit)
Returns int
Begin
    Declare @Rev varchar(50) = Reverse(@Value)
    Declare @Ret int = IIF(@Strip0s=0, CharIndex('.',@Rev)-1,CharIndex('.',Substring(@Rev, PatIndex('%[^0]%', @Rev+'.'), LEN(@Value)))-1)
    Return IIF(@Ret<0,0,@Ret)
End
```

Sample Results

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Scale](18.250,1)      Returns 2
Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Scale](18.250,0)      Returns 3
Select [dbo].[udf-Stat-Scale]('18.1234',1)   Returns 4
```

Comment: Did you test with trailing zeros?

Comment: @Shnugo I considered that after I saw your post, but then thought 18.50 has a scale of 2.  Perhaps an optional parameter to remove the trailing zeros would be best.

Comment: @Shnugo added the option to strip trailing zeros.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

A `varchar` has no scale...

For a generic approach it was easier to get the scale length with string methods entirely:

```
DECLARE  @ATempSelected TABLE(RowNum [int] ,Quantity1 sql_variant,
Quantity2 sql_variant)

INSERT INTO @ATempSelected
SELECT 1,  '18.33',18.33
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  '18.555555',18.555555;

SELECT T.*
       ,ScaleLength.*
FROM @ATempSelected AS T
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(Quantity1 AS VARCHAR(100)) AS q1
                  ,CAST(Quantity2 AS VARCHAR(100)) AS q2) AS AllText
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEN(AllText.q1)-CHARINDEX('.',AllText.q1) AS Scale1
                  ,LEN(AllText.q1)-CHARINDEX('.',AllText.q2) AS Scale2 ) AS ScaleLength
```

If you have string values with zeros at the end, you can use `REVERSE` and `PATINDEX` to find the first character other than zero from right side and cut this part away. Then re-reverse the string...